# cocos2d add layers on scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, addition, layer

I know that my question might be stupid but I searched and I can't find why it's not working.
I create a `CCLayer` class `BackgroundLayer` with implementation below:

```
#import "BackgroundLayer.h"

@implementation BackgroundLayer

- (id)init {
    if (self != nil) {
        CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"menu.png"];
        background.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);

        [self addChild:background z:-1];

        NSLog(@"test");
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

and I want to add it on main menu scene and I have:

```
#import "MainMenuScene.h"
#import "BackgroundLayer.h"

@implementation MainMenuScene

+ (id)scene { 
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    BackgroundLayer *backgroundLayer = [BackgroundLayer node];
    [scene addChild:backgroundLayer];
    return scene;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

My problem is that `NSLog` test appears but the background doesn't load. If I add the background on the `init` method of `MainMenuScene` it works... Shouldn't I suppose that the layer works this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if related but you forgot `self = [super init];` in BackgroundLayer.

Try commenting out the anchor point line to see if the image shows up then.

Comment: thank you,very much!!!
 that was the self=[]super init].
some times you are tired and beginner and you forget the details.